# Java Azure Function - upload file in BLOB Container

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to make an Azure Function in Java. I need to make an excel file and upload it in BLOB container.
When I build the project and the tests start, then it works without problems and it uploads the file in the container, when instead I debug the project or I deploy it on Azure and I run it via internet (calling the service), it doesn't upload it. It blocks when it tries to upload the file.
Can you help me please? I'm on this problem since a few days.

Thank you.

I attach the method where it uploads the file:

```
@FunctionName("FunctionTest")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    final String queryAccountName = request.getQueryParameters().get("AccountName");
    String accountName = request.getBody().orElse(queryAccountName);
    final String queryAccountKey = request.getQueryParameters().get("AccountKey");
    String accountKey = request.getBody().orElse(queryAccountKey);

    context.getLogger().info("Azure Blob storage v12 - Java quickstart sample\n");

    // Retrieve the connection string for use with the application. The storage
    // connection string is stored in an environment variable on the machine
    // running the application called AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING. If the environment variable
    // is created after the application is launched in a console or with
    // Visual Studio, the shell or application needs to be closed and reloaded
    // to take the environment variable into account.
    // String connectStr = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");

    //String connectStr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="+accountName+";AccountKey="+accountKey+";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    //BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
    StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
    String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();

    //Create a unique name for the container
    String containerName = "container-name";

    // Create the container and return a container client object
    //BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

    // Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
    /*String pathFile = "./data/";
    String fileName = "quickstart" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";
    File localFile = new File(pathFile + fileName);

    // Write text to the file
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(pathFile + fileName, true);
        writer.write("Hello, World!");
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    // Get a reference to a blob
    // Upload the blob
    String pathFile = System.getenv("TEMP") + "\\";
    String fileName = creaReport(context)+".xlsx"; // creating file Excel - IT DOESN'T EVEN WORK WITH TXT FILE
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

    System.out.println("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t" + blobClient.getBlobUrl());

    blobClient.uploadFromFile(pathFile + fileName, true);  // IT BLOCKS HERE

    System.out.println("\nListing blobs...");

    // List the blob(s) in the container.
    for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + blobItem.getName());
    }

    // Download the blob to a local file
    // Append the string "DOWNLOAD" before the .txt extension so that you can see both files.
    //String downloadFileName = fileName.replace(".txt", "DOWNLOAD.txt");
    String downloadFileName = fileName.replace(".xlsx", "DOWNLOAD.xlsx");
    File downloadedFile = new File(pathFile + downloadFileName);

    System.out.println("\nDownloading blob to\n\t " + pathFile + downloadFileName);

    blobClient.downloadToFile(pathFile + downloadFileName, true);

    // Clean up
    System.out.println("\nPress the Enter key to begin clean up");
    System.console().readLine();

    /*System.out.println("Deleting blob container...");
    containerClient.delete();*/

    System.out.println("Deleting the local source and downloaded files...");
    localFile.delete();
    downloadedFile.delete();

    System.out.println("Done");

    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Blob uploaded").build();

}
```

Comment: Where do you get the contents for creating the xlsx file... I would suggest that you use a Stream based approach instead of saving the file to disk... Could you provide some more info

Comment: Hi Fabio, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I test it in my side and summarize the point as below:

The reason for this problem is **the files in `local/temp` are not shared among site instances**. You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system).

[image]

So I met the same problem as you, I deploy my java function to azure and add a file under `local/temp` path manually. Then run the function, it can't access the data of the file.

After that, I edit my function code. Create a txt file by the code below in my function:

```
String filePath="d:\\local\\Temp\\test1.txt";
File file = new File(filePath);

try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.write("Test data");
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    context.getLogger().info(e1.getMessage());
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then read the file **in the same function** by the code below:

```
InputStream is = null;
int i;
char c;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
        c = (char) i;
        context.getLogger().info("===inputstream==" + c);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    context.getLogger().info("===try catch error");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            context.getLogger().info("===finally error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

Deploy the code to azure, the function app run in a consumption plan(so it will just use one instance if I just run it once). Running it, I read the data of the file success.

According to the test above, I suggest you do not create the file in `local/temp`. You'd better create the file in `d:\home\site\wwwroot`, you can create a folder under `wwwroot` and create the files in the folder. I test it works fine.

Hope it helps~